Pandas: How do I replace a subset of column values with the same column values in a specific series?
I'm writing a Pandas script to perform data manipulation on an excel file. First, I load two sheets into dataframes. One is the original data df, the second is a sheet detailing replacements that need to be made in the original data replace.
The script needs to do two things for each row of df.

Replace each instance of 'Name' in df with 'NameReplace' (working)

For the same rows in df, replace a slice of the columns (specified by a list) with the values in the same slice of columns in replace


Reproducible Minimal Example of my current implementation:
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([["John", None, None],["Phil", None, None],["John", None, None],["Bob", None, None]], columns=["Name", "Age", "Height"])
replace = pandas.DataFrame([["John", "Dom", 25, 175],["Phil", "Kevin", 56, 145],["Bob", "Michael", 33, 180]], columns=["Name", "NameReplace", "Age", "Height"])

detailsList = ["Age", "Height"]

for i, row in replace.iterrows():
    df.loc[df['Name'] == row['Name'], 'Name'] = row['NameReplace']
    df.loc[df['Name'] == row['NameReplace'], detailsList] = row[detailsList]

print(df)

Step 1) is working with this implementation, but the detailsList columns in df do not get populated.
The current output is
      Name  Age Height
0      Dom  NaN    NaN
1    Kevin  NaN    NaN
2      Dom  NaN    NaN
3  Michael  NaN    NaN

The desired output is
      Name  Age Height
0      Dom  25    175
1    Kevin  56    145
2      Dom  25    175
3  Michael  33    180

I've been trying for a while now, and cannot seem to make progress. I also don't really get why this doesn't work, so any insight there would be extra appreciated!
Note: Using detailsList to specify the slice of columns is necessary, as in the real solution I am only operating on a specific slice of the full dataframe, unlike the example I've given.

I also realise in general using iterrows() is frowned upon in pandas for performance reasons. 'replace' is over 200x smaller than 'df', as 'replace' has just one row for each unique value in 'df'. So it seemed ok to me and I don't know what else to use lol

You can also avoid the iterrows using a merge, adding that in as well

It's unfortunate that this question has now been closed with duplicate suggestions that do not address a more proper way to achieve this result, which would for instance be to use df.merge: (df[['Name']].merge(replace, on='Name', how='left').drop('Name', axis=1).rename(columns={'NameReplace': 'Name'})). That should be way faster on a significant dataset than using iterrows.

An alternative, equally way faster: (replace.set_index('Name').reindex(df['Name']).reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'NameReplace': 'Name'})).

@o The reindexing approach is nice, thanks for sharing

The problem is the way that pandas tries to assign a series to a whole dataframe. Anyway, here's a simple fix that leads to the intended behavior, taking advantage that pandas does the correct thing when you assign with a numpy array rather than with a series.
for i, row in replace.iterrows():
    df.loc[df['Name'] == row['Name'], 'Name'] = row['NameReplace']
    df.loc[df['Name'] == row['NameReplace'], detailsList] = row[detailsList].values


Other optimizations:

Note that you can reuse the df['Name'] == row['Name'] mask. In particular, you save some work with

for i, row in replace.iterrows():
    mask = df['Name'] == row['Name']
    df.loc[mask, 'Name'] = row['NameReplace']
    df.loc[mask, detailsList] = row[detailsList].values


You can avoid iterrows if you use a merge

df = (df[['Name']].merge(replace, on = 'Name')
                  .drop(columns='Name')
                  .rename(columns={'NameReplace':'Name'}))

The catch with this approach is that the rows might end up reordered.

Another approach, taking advantage of indexing:

df = (replace.set_index('Name')
             .loc[df['Name'].values]
             .reset_index(drop=True)
             .rename(columns={'NameReplace': 'Name'}))


Thanks! Interesting about the mask in your example, you have taught me something good sir.

@Ineruditus You got it. Be sure to check my latest edit as well
